# Catch limit of firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, offline-caching

I am using firebase in android app and noticed that catch memory increasing rapidly.

What is Catch limit of firebase? and how to set limit ?

Comment: Do you mean cache (instead of "catch")?  How are you measuring this, and how do you know it's a result of Firebase, instead of your own code?

Comment: here you can limit your data with `limitToFirst()` or `limitToLast()` options. check the link for more detail : https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data

Comment: Ohh sry ..its cache. When I open my app it loads all data from firebase and so the cache memory which shows in setting increasing..how to set limit for same? Or there is any limit? Will it cause any issue

Comment: @HakanC how to load more data on scroll when using limittofirst or limitto last.. thanks

Comment: Actually I don't know how to do at android. I can give some idea only js. With page position listening.